# MERN - Connect Front and Back End

Tags: reactjs, api, express, axios, mern

I am new on web development.. Sorry if the question sounds stupid or if I had mess up with my code.

I have this problem: I've tried to create a simple "To Do List" application using MERN stack.

I did connect React with the backend: I can send get and post request and they are working (i'm adding items to my mongoDB).

Here comes the issue: I cannot delete item from my list. The delete request is not working because I'm not able to get my item ID in react and honestly I don't know why.

Here it is my react code:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4FBi.jpg)

The problem should be that I'm not getting the ID of my data... But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Insert code as code, not as screenshot please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that instead of passing the id to deleteNow function, you are passing the parameters from the onPress event.

So, if you want to make it work, do this change:

change:
 `onPress={deleteNow}` to `onPress={() => deleteNow(data._id)}`

Answer (score 0):

Update onPress={() => deleteNow(data._id)} . if you not did that in SingleItem component

I am adding one more point.

**your code**
In addNote function - 
1.update the state data with newItem received in the function.
2.then updated the Db.
now, the problem is the newItem added to data state won't have _id property because it is not from db.

**my suggestion**
1. post your data as you did with axios.
2. received the newly added db document via response and add to data state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm noticing now that there is this issue: I can insert a new item but that item doesn't have an id until I will refresh the page. (it means that for example I cannot delete it before the refresh). 

In this way seems to work, but I don't know if it is the best one:
function addNote(newItem){
        
       setData (prevItems => [...prevItems, {name: newItem}]);

        axios.post("/api/items", {name: newItem });
        axios.get("/api/items")
            .then(result => setData(result.data))}